# Wrong post_type argument passed to the query when using a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm trying to obtain a structure like this

```
1) Posts -> /%category%/articles/%postname%/
2) CPT   -> /%category%/CPT/%postname%/
```

But although I am able to see the right URL in the address bar, the page return a "404 error".

Digging this down I noticed that the query that WP sends is not correct

```
SELECT   wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_name = 'win' AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
```

The post_type argument should be - in my case - qualifications as this is the name of the CPT.

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Is there any relationship with the add_permstruct function?

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: How will you deal with a CPT that is in the sub category 'articles'? How do you intend to deal with clashes?

Comment: How isn't this a continuation of your other post? http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/151617/custom-slug-for-a-custom-post-type-and-default-post

Comment: @vancoder this is not really a continuation. In the other post I was trying to get the solution, here try to understand why WP is not using the right term while querying.

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm not planning to have any sub-category at present. Do you have any recommendation by any chance?

Comment: You may want to look into ensuring that sub-categories aren't possible, or an additional custom taxonomy that is non-hierarchical

Comment: @TomJNowell how can a hierarchical taxonomy affect the situation? The hierarchy in WP is still a murder mystery to me. Do you have something I can read to clear out my mind?

Comment: A sub category has a parent, thus there is a hierarchy with the parent category on the top. Categories are hierarchical. Tags are not, as tags cant have parent or child terms, so you can't form a hierarchy. If categories were non-heirarchical, they would behave like tags